# Reading data from SharePoint list and show it on web part using ID

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint list Called Leave Request.I would like to read 6 values from there and show it on a custom web part.The custom web part will display the output on labels.I want to use id to populate the labels.

Comment: Are you using Data View WebPart?

Comment: I am not using Data View WebPart.It is just a normal custom WebPart with Output labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below mentioned function to get first 6 rows from your list. I assumed that you are using server side code to get list data.

```
public void getData()
{
    // choose your site
    string strUrl = "Insert your site URL here";
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            // choose the list
            SPList list = web.Lists["insert your list Name"];

            SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
            myquery.RowLimit = 6;
            myquery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy>";

            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(myquery);

            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                // check the item for null
                if (item != null)
                {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I would like to read about 6 fields using the ID on site URL .